# How to know what actual files are being bundled by React Native?

Tags: react-native, bundler

I feel my app has grown in size significantly in recent versions and it's not clear why. Is there any way to know what exact files the React Native bundler is going to include in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library to visualize the contents of the bundle.
[react-native-bundle-visualizer](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-bundle-visualizer)